# React Native / Firebase - Creating unique username

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

So after a user has presses the register button, I want to send the data to a cloud function called `Register()`.
The data that I send is first name, last name, date of birth etc.

I form the username by lower-casing the first name and last name and then joining them up. I want to check if the username exists, then add a number until unique username created. If the username does not exist (meaning its unique), create user account with email and password and store data in firestore.

I check if username exists by a `username` collection in Firestore with all taken usernames.

Right now the way I do this is with a while async loop at the client side but I want to move this to cloud functions for more security. I tried using the same method with async while loop but firebase cloud functions does not accept await in loops.

Any ideas on how to do this? Perhaps recursion? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: My problem is that I do not know where to start to implement this certain feature for my app. Just need guidance